# Check connection without "Test-Connection"

Tags: powershell

I want program a script that check if the computer has Internet or not, and I'm thought in ipconfig, but I don't want specify if I'm connected with wifi, Ethernet, etc.

Can I use another command?

Answer (score 2):

if you have powershell v3 at least you can une `invoke-webrequest` :

```
iwr "google.com" |select statuscode, statusdescription
```

Comment: please elaborate your question as actually it's hard to tell what do you expect?

Comment: Test-Connection is as Invoke-WebRequest, It creates a connection with the world (server) and I want check if I has connection locally. For example, my virtual machine can be connected to another NEW network card than my host, and it will be nice has a universal solution to check my connection.

Comment: your question was about to check for internet availability, not local area networks... so you want to get all ip adapters and their ip adress of a computer that's right ?

Comment: I want check if I've connection with the world with Ehternet, Wifi, 3G, VPNs, etc. but no sending packets to Google.com or another service.